# How to find remainder in this case

Tags: polynomials

I am asked to find the remainder when $1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots+x^{22}$ is divided by $1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots +x^{11}$

Here's my attempt at it.

I tried summing the GP

Let $P(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{11} = \frac{x^{12}-1}{x-1}$

$P(x^2)=1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots+x^{22}=\frac{x^{24}-1}{x^2-1}$

So I let $P(x^2)=P(x) \times q(x)+r(x)$, where $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ are the quotient and remainder polynomials respectively.

Noticing that $P(x) \times q(x)= 0$ for $x = -1$, I'd still have to consider $r(x)$ as a tenth degree polynomial and try to solve for coefficients, and anyways $P(x^2)$ would be undefined for $x=-1$, not a particularly effective method.

I tried using congruence modulo but that still doesn't get me to the right answer. How do I approach this?

Comment: Writing $\frac{x^{12}-1}{x-1}$ and other rational functions is a bit dangerous here because you want to stay in the realm of polynomials. You also should avoid thinking of $x$ as any particular number; these polynomials are not functions, they are elements of a ring.

Comment: The $q(x)$ should have degree 11, and can be computed by a tedious polynomial division, or an almost guess-and-check procedure. Then whatever is left over is the remainder

Comment: Starter for the polynomial division: the coefficient of $x^{11}$ in $q(x)$ is $1$, and that will force the coefficient of $x^{10}$ to be $-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continue:

$P(x)= 1 + x + ... +x^{11} = \frac {x^{12}-1}{x-1}$

And $Q(x) = 1+x^2 + ... + x^{22} = \frac{x^{24}-1}{x^2 -1}$

And $\frac {Q(x)}{P(x)} = \frac {(x^{24}-1)(x-1)}{(x^{12}-1)(x^2-1)}=\frac{(x^{12}-1)(x^{12}+1)(x-1)}{(x^{12}-1)(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac{x^{12}+1}{x+1}$

$=\frac{x^{12}+x^{11} -(x^{11}+x^{10})+(x^{10}-x^9)-(x^9+x^8)+...+(x^2+x) - (x+1) +2}{x-1}= x^{11}-x^{10}+x^9-....+ x-1 + \frac 2{x+1}$.

Now we just need to solve $\frac 2{x+1} = \frac {R(x)}{1+x + ... + x^{11}}$ or

$R(x) = \frac {2[(1+x) + (x^2 + x^3) + .... + (x^{10}+x^{11})]}{1+x}=$

$2(1+x^2 + ... + x^{10}) = 2+2x^2 + 2x^4 + 2x^6 + 2x^8 + 2x^{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\ x^{24}-1= \left(x^{12}-1\right)\left(x^{12}+1\right)\ $

Answer (score 0):

$$x^{11}+...+x^2+x+1 = (x+1)(x^{10}+x^8+...x^2+1)=(x+1){x^{12}-1\over x^2-1}$$

So we have $${x^{24}-1\over x^2-1} = q(x)(x+1){x^{12}-1\over x^2-1}+ r(x)$$

where $r$ is of degree 10 or less and thus we get $$x^{12}+1 =(x+1)q(x)+{(x^2-1)r(x)\over x^{12}-1}$$

So $$1+x^2+...+x^{10}\mid r(x)$$ which means $$r(x)= c(1+x^2+...+x^{10})$$